# Sony VAIO VPC-Z13-BGX with Windows 7 64-bit: Bluetooth devices freezing

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, bluetooth, sony-vaio

I have a problem with all Bluetooth devices freezing for 5-30 seconds. I went through all the Sony tech support steps of restoring the system, etc. to no avail. Sony sent out a technician with new Bluetooth hardware, which did not solve the problem.

I've discovered that the Bluetooth problem goes away when I have Wi-Fi turned off. Presumably this is a driver problem, or maybe the order in which the drivers are loaded.

When checking the device manager, there are no problems shown -- no interrupt or other conflicts.

Comment: not a driver problem.  see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some wireless standards operate at 2.4Ghz(as does bluetooth), so until the intereference is accounted for and they select only channels that are not currently clashing...Just my 2 cents.  Switching to use only the 5.4Ghz bands on your wireless(802.11a) may fix it.